# Can a primary key of one table be a foreign key of another table?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a scenario like this :
I have an **employee** table which has columns like this

```
Employee_ID
First_Name
Last_Name
Employee_Designation
```

Also I have a **Joining_Vital** table

```
Employee_ID
Joining_ID
Joining_Date
```

How can I link this two tables ?
As I guess it would be a many-to-one relationship(as one joining_vital can contain many employees) from **Employee** table to  **Joining_Vital** table

I cannot establish the foreign key on the **Employee_ID** column of the Employee table.
I am naive to Database thing
Could you guys please help me out how to do it?
I cannot figure out the scenario
Please explain me out. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: "*I cannot establish the foreign key on the Employee_ID column of the Employee table*" - why? What error do you get? What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: I guess when I try to make the same column as PK and FK also MySQL not allowing me to do so

Comment: Please share the commands you execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the forums. A simple Google led me [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp).

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  Employee_ID INT,
  First_name VARCHAR(25),
  Last_name VARCHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (Employee_ID),  -- Must be present - otherwise you cannot create the FOREIGN KEY
  Employee_designation VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE joining_vital
(
  Employee_ID INT(10),
  Joining_ID INT(10),
  Joining_date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID) REFERENCES employee (Employee_ID)
);
```

Take a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour) and also [here](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) - help us to help you! These forums are a great resource and you will get more out of them if you take the trouble to follow the guidelines.